# Are PHP APCU operations atomic

Tags: php, atomic, apcu

I've just started using APCU caching in my PHP application.

However, I was wondering whether the operations are atomic or not.

The documentation (e.g.: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.apcu-store.php) it just states:

> Unlike many other mechanisms in PHP, variables stored using apcu_store() will persist between requests (until the value is removed from the cache).

This sounds atomic for me: Request A can read the old value until request B has completely written the new value.

Do I get this correct?

Comment: Yes, there is locking involved.